# JavaScript script in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hi I'm using jQuery in my ASP.NET website.
I try to make slider using scripts

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css-default")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css-menu")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css-style")

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/slider")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function() {
             $('.banner').unslider({
                 speed: 500,
                 delay: 3000,
                 complete: function() {},
                 keys: false,
                 dots: true,
                 fluid: false
             });});


    </script>


</head>
```

in version where i don't use ASP.NET script is working, but when I copied it to Layout.cshtml it doeas not...

```
<div id="slider">
  <div class="banner">
    <ul>
      <li><img src="~/Images/1.jpg"></li>
      <li><img src="~/Images/2.jpg"></li>
      <li><img src="~/Images/3.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include jQuery before you include your slider library because the library uses jQuery:

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/slider")
```

Comment: thx, I've been fighting with it for almost an hour :) It's working now